# Tic Tac Toe victory check

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am writing Python code for a Tic Tac Toe game.  I need to write a function that takes in three inputs: board, x, and y.  Board being the current display of the board and then x and y being values of 0, 1, or 2.  The game is set up to ask the user for coordinates.

```
def CheckVictory(board, x, y):

    #check if previous move was on vertical line and caused a win
    if board[0][y] == ('X') and board[1][y] == ('X') and board [2][y] == ('X'):
        return True
    if board[0][y] == ('O') and board[1][y] == ('O') and board [2][y] == ('O'):
        return True

    #check if previous move was on horizontal line and caused a win
    if board[x][0] == ('X') and board[x][1] == ('X') and board [x][2] == ('X'):
        return True
    if board[x][0] == ('O') and board[x][1] == ('O') and board [x][2] == ('O'):
        return True

    #check if previous move was on the main diagonal and caused a win
    if board[0][0] == ('X') and board[1][1] == ('X') and board [2][2] == ('X'):
        return True
    if board[0][0] == ('O') and board[1][1] == ('O') and board [2][2] == ('O'):
        return True
    #check if previous move was on the secondary diagonal and caused a win
    if board[0][2] == ('X') and board[1][1] == ('X') and board [2][0] == ('X'):
        return True
    if board[0][2] == ('O') and board[1][1] == ('O') and board [2][0] == ('O'):
        return True

    return False 
#end of CheckVictory function
```

The function is called in the game loop like so:

```
p_x, p_y = playerTurn(board)    #let player take turn
displayBoard(board)             #show board after move has been made
if CheckVictory(board, p_x, p_y):   #see if user has won
    print("CONGRATULATIONS, you win!")
    newGame(board)  #game over start new one
    continue
```

and it's similar for the computer turn.

I feel like there is a better way to write this function.  I feel like I should be using x and y more or there is a better way to check rather than writing all the possibilities. What's a better way to write this to make it short and concise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that a mark has been placed at `board[x][y]`. Then you only need this to check for a win on vertical line `y`:

```
if board[0][y] == board[1][y] == board [2][y]
```

Your comments state "check if previous move was on the main/secondary diagonal", but you don't actually check. You can use the expressions `x == y` and `x + y == 2` to check that.

Simplified code:

```
def CheckVictory(board, x, y):

    #check if previous move caused a win on vertical line 
    if board[0][y] == board[1][y] == board [2][y]:
        return True

    #check if previous move caused a win on horizontal line 
    if board[x][0] == board[x][1] == board [x][2]:
        return True

    #check if previous move was on the main diagonal and caused a win
    if x == y and board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board [2][2]:
        return True

    #check if previous move was on the secondary diagonal and caused a win
    if x + y == 2 and board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board [2][0]:
        return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start by removing duplication.  If you pass in the mark that the player being checked is using, then you can eliminate 1/2 your code.

```
def CheckVictory(board, x, y, mark):

    if board[x][0] == (mark) and board[x][1] == (mark) and board [x][2] == (mark):
           return True

    if board[0][y] == (mark) and board[1][y] == (mark) and board [2][y] == (mark):
           return True

    #check if previous move was on the main diagonal and caused a win
    if board[0][0] == (mark) and board[1][1] == (mark) and board [2][2] == (mark):
           return True

    #check if previous move was on the secondary diagonal and caused a win
    if board[0][2] == (mark) and board[1][1] == (mark) and board [2][0] == (mark):
           return True    

    return False 

#end of CheckVictory function
```

Please excuse me if I have syntax wrong, I've never used python before.

Comment: ...or set `mark = board[x][y]` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will check horizontal lines, vertical lines and diagonal lines for a winner and return the player number. I just used player numbers 1, 2 instead of 'x', 'o' to avoid numpy array conversions.

```
board = np.empty((BOARD_SIZE,BOARD_SIZE))
winner_line = [
    np.array([1, 1, 1]),
    np.array([2, 2, 2])
]

def CheckVictory(board):
    for idx in range(BOARD_SIZE):
        row = board[idx, :]
        col = board[:, idx]
        diagonal_1 = np.diagonal(board)
        diagonal_2 = np.diagonal(np.fliplr(board))

        # Check for each player
        for player in range(1,3):
            if np.all(row == winner_line[player-1]) \
                    or np.all(col == winner_line[player-1]) \
                    or np.all(diagonal_1 == winner_line[player-1]) \
                    or np.all(diagonal_2 == winner_line[player-1]):
                return player # There is a winner
    return False # No winner
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start you could make your code twice smaller by removing the logic common to 'X' and to 'O'.
Then, you can perform all the comparisons in one go.

```
def CheckVictory(board, x, y):
    playerSymbols=['X','O']

    #check if previous move was on vertical line and caused a win
    if (board[0][y] in playerSymbols) and board[0][y] == board[1][y] ==  board[2][y]:

    #check if previous move was on horizontal line and caused a win
    if (board[x][0] in playerSymbols) and board[x][0] == board[x][1] == board [x][2]:
        return True

    #check if previous move was on the main diagonal and caused a win
    if (board[0][0] in playerSymbols) and board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board [2][2]:

    #check if previous move was on the secondary diagonal and caused a win
    if (board[0][2] in playerSymbols) and board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board [2][0]:
        return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- `CheckVictory`: Idiomatic in Python is `check_victory`.
- `CheckVictory(board, x, y)`: I think you are mixing two things here, putting a value in the board and checking if someone won. Your function should be doing only one thing, checking if someone won on a given `board`.
- A standard approach is to prepare all the data you need (here, the positions/coordinates to check) and leave the code as simple as possible.

I'd write:

```
positions_groups = (
    [[(x, y) for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)] + # horizontals
    [[(x, y) for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)] + # verticals
    [[(d, d) for d in range(3)]] + # diagonal from top-left to bottom-right
    [[(2-d, d) for d in range(3)]] # diagonal from top-right to bottom-left
)

def get_winner(board):
    """Return winner piece in board (None if no winner)."""
    for positions in positions_groups:
        values = [board[x][y] for (x, y) in positions]
        if len(set(values)) == 1 and values[0]:
            return values[0]

board = [
    ["X", "X", "O"],
    ["O", "X", "X"],
    ["O", "X", "O"],
]

print(get_winner(board)) # "X"
```

Comment: "I think you are mixing two things here" - no, it's just using the location of the last move (which must be part of any newly-created victory) to narrow down the scope of the search.